# Default to blank string in Twig template if translation is not found

Tags: symfony, twig, twig-extension

Is there a way to default to a blank string rather than the translation key in the event the translation has not been found in a Twig template?

I am attempting this sort of thing using the `default` Twig filter alongside the `trans` filter however this does not work:

```
{{ 'crmpicco.general.course.opening_hours_weekend'|default('')|trans }}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the default after the trans filter?

Comment: @Seer Yes, I tried that. Unfortunately it does not work by putting `default('')` at the end after the `trans` filter.

Comment: If there's no solution to it that you can find with the built-in filters, you could always make your own. It's really easy to do: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

Comment: @Seer Thanks for the suggestion. I am familiar with custom Twig extensions, however I was just posting to see if this can be done with standard Twig functionality.

Comment: Fair enough :), I think you may be out of luck in that case it seems!

Comment: Not with the trans filter itself. The translator is not intended to do so.

Comment: @Paziツ I hoped that with a combination of filters it would be possible.

Comment: Sadly no. In the message catalogue its hardcoded to return the id if no translation is found. But you can overwrite the twig filter

Answer (score 2):

You can overwrite the translation extension with your own, so the `trans` and `transchoice` filter would behave as you want:

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Twig/EmptyTranslationExtension.php

namespace AppBundle\Twig;

use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\TranslationExtension;

class EmptyTranslationExtension extends TranslationExtension
{
    public function trans($message, array $arguments = [], $domain = null, $locale = null)
    {
        $value = parent::trans($message, $arguments, $domain, $locale);

        return ($message === $value) ? '' : $value;
    }

    public function transchoice($message, $count, array $arguments = [], $domain = null, $locale = null)
    {
        $value = parent::transchoice($message, $count, array_merge(['%count%' => $count], $arguments), $domain, $locale);

        return ($message === $value) ? '' : $value;
    }
}
```

And register your extension as replacement for the default one:

```
# app/config/services.yml

services:
    twig.extension.trans:
        class: AppBundle\Twig\EmptyTranslationExtension
        public: false
        arguments:
            - @translator
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

Answer (score 0):

This way work, but it is not an optimal solution:

```
{% set trans_key = 'crmpicco.general.course.opening_hours_weekend' %}
{% set trans_value = trans_key | trans %}

{{ trans_key == trans_value ? '' : trans_value }}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, this likely wouldn't be very maintainable for a template where there are a number of translations though.

Answer (score 0):

This part works for me:

```
{{ crmpicco.general.course.opening_hours_weekend == '' ? '' : crmpicco.general.course.opening_hours_weekend|trans() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's even easier than that. you can simply cast the type to string by concatenating with a string.

```
{{ null ~ ''|trans }}
```

but given the choice, clean data would be better. or a fix in the translationextension